# How to make the UI view fill the entire XAML Designer Window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, designer

I am trying to design a UI with the XAML Designer in Visual Studio Community 2017.

I added some rows and columns and so far things are ok but what annoys me is that the area I am working on (i.e. the view of my UI in progress) fills only part of the Designer window.

[image: white area fills only fraction of designer window]

How can I make the white area (which represents the UI) fill the entire designer window?

***************************************UPDATE***********************************

Upon request I added the XAML code below.
(However, in my opinion the XAML code doesn't matter. What I'm looking for is a menu option in the IDE to make the UI representation fill the designer window. I can choose among different percentages at the bottom left of the designer window. However, this makes the UI representation either far too big or far too small. What I'm looking for is a full window view of the UI in progress.)

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="405.333">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
Margin="-1444,-3849,-1427,2880">

   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
    Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="42" Width="140"/>


</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Show the Xaml. Not much we can do with the image

Comment: That behavior is by design. You can use your mouse wheel or the zoom dropdown in the bottom left corner of the design window to make it consume more space or double click the hand icon in the left toolbar to bring it into view automatically. I should add though, all those hard set negative and positive margins is poor layout practice and will cause you issues from one device to another.

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for your answer. I can't see a hand icon anywhere though. Where exactly is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Tommy, Xaml does matter. because if you understand the xaml then you will know what to do in the properties panel.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom left of the designer, you'll find the following combobox:

[image]

Select what you want in the designer then press "Fit selection". Then it will fill the whole space.

Comment: I tried that before ... it doesn't work ... when I select the UI in progress (i.e. the white area in my screenshot) and the press  "Fit selection", the UI still makes up only a fraction of the designer window.

Comment: Hold control and scroll in then?

Comment: that's the work around I have resorted to ... but I hoped there was a full size option somewhere

Comment: @Tommy The Fit to selection works for what's selected.  
Your white space is empty, which  means there is nothing to select there. So Visual Studio fits to the selected button.

As J R says, use the Control key and mouse scroll wheel, then hold the Space bar to activated the Hand cursor, then you can drag the designer to correct position with the mouse.

Comment: ok, finally I understood how to get that hand cursor ... Thank you!

Comment: @Walt: do you by any chance also know the answer to this question?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968381/grouping-two-elements-to-a-stackpanel-upends-the-ui-visual-studio-xaml